# Как использовать Intbuffer с FileChanel с RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, filechanel, randomaccessfile

Нужно записать строку, для этого использую `FileChanel` and `IntBuffer`, чтобы скорость записи была высокой, но получаю ошибку `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException` - позиция больше лимита, но почему так происходит?
И код:

```
public void write(String string) throws IOException {
    FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(
            new File(FILE_NAME), MODE_RW).getChannel();
    IntBuffer ib = fc.map(
            FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, fc.size()).asIntBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.toCharArray().length; i++) {
        ib.put(string.toCharArray()[i]);
    }
    fc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал немного по иному, но скорость все равно не снизилась.

```
public void write(String path, String string) throws IOException {
    FileChannel ch = setFileChanel(path, MODE_RW);
    ch.write(setByteBuffer(string));
    ch.close();
}

private FileChannel setFileChanel(String path, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new RandomAccessFile(new File(path), mode).getChannel();
}

private ByteBuffer setByteBuffer(String string){
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes());
}
```